# Sorting strings without methods and other types

Tags: python-3.x, string

Hello I have to reorder a string, I am banned from using other types and str methods

So my problem is that I could not figure out how to end my code to get it work with any string
I tried to compare the results with sorted() to check and I am stuck at the first exchange
My code:

```
i = 0
s1 = "hello"
s2 = sorted(s1)
while (i<len(s1)):
    j=i+1
    while (j<=len(s1)-1):
        if (s1[i] > s1[j]):
            s1 = s1[0:i] + s1[j] + s1[i]
        j+=1
    i+=1

print(s1)
print(s2)
```

I tried to add `+ s1[len(s1):]` at the end of the operation but
I only had found the result for a single string(that I was testing) adding this
I am really stuck, how can I make it work for all the strings with different lenghts??

 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not reconstructing the string correctly when doing `s1 = s1[0:i] + s1[j] + s1[i]` as you're replacing one character for the other but you omit to actually interchange the two and to add the remains of the splitted string to the end of the new string.

Given what your code looks like, I would do it like this:

```
i = 0
s1 = "hello"
s2 = sorted(s1)

while i < len(s1):
    j = i + 1
    while j <= len(s1)-1:
        if s1[i] > s1[j]:
            s1 = s1[0:i] + s1[j] + s1[i+1:j] + s1[i] + s1[j+1:len(s1)]
        j += 1
    i += 1

print("".join(s2))
# > 'ehllo'

print(s1)
# > 'ehllo'
```

Please tell me if anything is unclear!

Answer (score 1):

> I am banned from using other types and str methods

Based upon your criteria, your request is impossible. Just accessing the elements of a string requires string methods.

The technique that you are using is very convoluted, hard to read and is difficult to debug. Try running your code in a debugger.

Now given that you are allowed to convert a string to a list (which requires string methods), redesign your code to use simple, easy to understand statements.

The following code first converts the string into a list. Then loops thru the list starting at the beginning and compares each following character to the end. If any character is less then the current character, swap. As you step thru the string, the character swaps will result in a sorted list. At the end convert the list back to a string using join().

```
msg = 'hello'
s = list(msg)

for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(s)):
                if s[i] <= s[j]:
                        continue
                # swap characters
                s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]

print(msg)
print(''.join(s))
```

Comment: Code-only answers are ill-advised. Please add some explanation to improve this answer's quality.

Comment: @SuperKogito - For a simple string sort?

Comment: The answer is showing up in the Review queue for Low quality posts and I am afraid that it might end up deleted with its current form.

Comment: @SuperKogito - I am not aware of a low quality posts section. Can you provide the link that shows my answer?

Comment: I don't have the direct link to your post since I skipped it so it is not in my history logs but here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review) to the reviews section.

Comment: @SuperKogito - Thanks for the tip. I will keep that in mind for future answers. I did update this answer.

Comment: @SuperKogito - I have been on this site for several years and I did not know about the low quality list. Just shows that there is always something new to learn no matter how much you know.